# Kahler differentials of quotient field of regular local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a regular local ring, $k$ its residue field. Assume $k$ is perfect and $A$ is the localization of finitely generated algebra. Then $\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_A K \cong \Omega_{K/k}$.

I want to show this to be true. I can see how the result would lead straight from the existence of a split exact sequence  $0\to A\to K\to k\to 0$. But I can't see how this would be exact.

Comment: You are assuming that $A$ is a $k$-algebra, right?

Answer (score 1):

This isjust the consequence of a more general statement.

For a multiplicatively closed subset $S$ of $A$,
$$ S^{-1}\Omega_A/k\simeq \Omega_{S^{-1}A/k}.$$

See Hartshorne, Chapter II, Proposition 8.2A.

Now for $S=A-0$, $\Omega_A/k\otimes _A K =S^{-1}\Omega_A/k$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't see it! You are connecting two different parts of the proposition. You still need to have $K=A\otimes_k k$, to get $\Omega_{K/k}=\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_A K$, correct? I don't see how $K=A\otimes_k k$ is true

Comment: I am using that  $S^{-1}A=K$ for $S=A-\{0\}$. If you recall the definiton of the faction field $K$ of $A$, it is exactly the localization of $A$ along the multiplicatively closed set $S=A-0$.

Comment: Yes, so $S^{-1}A=K$ implies $S^{-1}\Omega_{A/k}=\Omega_{S^{-1}A/k}$. How does this lead to $S^{-1}\Omega_{A/k}=\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_A K$?

Comment: That is again a general statement: for an $A$-module $M$, $S^{-1}M\simeq S^{-1}A\otimes_A M$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!